# Angular's factory method not being called

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-services

In my `services.js` file I have the following `$resource` to connect to my RestAPI...

```
app.factory('Profile', function ($resource) {
    console.log("here");
    var Bear = $resource('http://192.168.0.11:3000/api/bears/:id', {id:'@id'});
    Bear.save({name:"Yogi"});
});
```

Now, I am trying to test whether it is working, but `console.log("here");` is never reached.

This is my `app.js` file containing my controller...

```
var app = angular.module('starter',
      [
      'ionic',
      'ngResource'
      ]
   );

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
       // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
   });
 });
```

As you can see I included `ngResource` but still the factory method is not called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Your factory doesn't return anything. 2) You would need to inject your `Profile` factory somewhere in order for it to be created and the contents executed. This will happen only once though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Phil mentioned, your factory is just sitting there doing nothing because:

1. It isn't injected into any controller or service. (or in your case the app.run block)

Solution: Inject it into the app.run block next to $ionicPlatform

2. The `Profile` factory should be called from the app.run block using a method called saveBear.

Solution: Change the code in services.js to this:

```
app.factory('Profile', function ($resource) {
    var saveBear = function(){
      console.log("here");
      var Bear = $resource('http://192.168.0.11:3000/api/bears/:id',{id:'@id'});
      Bear.save({name:"Yogi"});
    }

  return {
    saveBear: saveBear
  }

});
```

Then call the method in the run block using the statement

`Profile.saveBear();`

Comment: I put `Profile.saveBear();` in the run, and I'm getting `Profile not defined`. is there something else I need to add?

Comment: Include Profile in the services dependency next to $ionicPlatform in this line  `app.run(function($ionicPlatform, Profile) {`  . Also, have you included the file services.js in the index.html? If not do it.

Comment: haha it worked. Thanks for the help, I've been stressing over this quite some time